# How can I get the network driver that a particular docker container is using?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

I'm trying to debug some docker containers that aren't allowing outgoing connections. The [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/) says that allowing outgoing connections is the default behavior of the default `bridge` network driver, but that the `none` driver does not allow outgoing connections. I'd like to be able to check which network driver these containers are using, but I haven't been able to find the right switches in `docker ps` (or any other command) that would allow me to do this.

**How can I get the network driver for a particular docker container from the command line?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `docker container inspect` to view the `NetworkMode` attribute of the container:

```
docker container inspect <container> --format '{{ .HostConfig.NetworkMode }}'
```

This will either be:

- `host` when running with `--net=host`
- `none` when running with `--net=none`
- `default` when using the default bridge network
- `container:<id>` when using the namespace of another container
- otherwise it will be the name of a Docker network (and you would inspect the network for further details)